# How can we transform the products variable into the detailedProducts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, frontend

I've started on JS not long ago and I would like to know How can we transform the products variable into the detailedProducts in JavaScript

```
const products = [ 
  { title: 'Yellow Pail', 
  submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/daniel.jpg', 
  productImageUrl: 'images/products/image-aqua.png', 
  }, 
  { title: 'Supermajority: The Fantasy Congress League', 
  submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/kristy.png', 
  productImageUrl: 'images/products/image-rose.png', 
  }, 
  { title: 'The art of cooking', 
  submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/james.png', 
  productImageUrl: 'images/products/image-gold.png', 
  } 
  ] 
  const detailedProducts = [ 
  { 
  detail: 'This book was submitted by Daniel', 
  title: 'Yellow Pail', 
  submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/Daniel.jpg' 
  }, { 
  detail: 'This book was submitted by Kristy', 
  title: 'Supermajority: The Fantasy Congress League', 
  submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/Kristy.png' 
  }, 
  { 
  detail: 'This book was submitted by James ', 
  title: 'The art of cooking', 
  submitterAvatarUrl: 'images/avatars/James.png' 
  } 
  ]
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transform into", and what would be the expected output? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `title` and `submitterAvatarUrl` properties are identical in `product` and `detailedProducts`. You can produce the `detail` property by parsing the `submitterAvatarUrl` property of the `products` items:

```js
const detailedProducts = [];
products.forEach(p => {
   const parts = p.submitterAvatarUrl.split('/');
   const name = parts[parts.length - 1].split('.')[0];
   const capitalizedName = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
   const detailedProduct = {
       detail: 'This book was submitted by ' + capitalizedName,
       title : p.title,
       submitterAvatarUrl: p.submitterAvatarUrl
   };
   detailedProducts.push(detailedProduct);
});
```